# Text and table on single row and vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to have text and table inside another table cell and have them on a single row and vertically aligned.

Basically this code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      text:
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To yield this result:

```
text: a b
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3uxcn5pz/

---- stop reading here to avoid cry of desperate  non-GUI programmer -----

I'm trying space-wrap, floating, displays, line heights etc. 
But I cannot seem to accomplish this simple thing in a time that I need to build a space rocket guiding module. Instead I feel like html+CSS is there to torture innocent programmers (and if that's not enough - throw Javascript to the mix)

Comment: i don't understand. why have table inside a td ? when you can have 3tds on same row...and the problem is solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set both tables to `display: inline-table` and use the `vertical-align` property.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/vtxeyexu/1/)

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
}

td {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      text:
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      text:
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Magic!! You made my day and restored my believes in web GUI!